# Open in [MyAppName] from WKWebView

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

Can I achieve the Open in [MyAppName] banner using a WKWebView?
[Open in MyAppName](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NjCv9.png)

I have submitted an app [written in Swift] which prompts the user to sign in to a google account through Safari and open a .csv file of a report. When the report is opened the user is presented with the Open in [MyAppName] banner. They click it, the app launches with the contents of the URL and it all works perfectly.

Apple have rejected the app saying that navigating the user to Safari is a 'poor user experience' and suggest I use a Safari View Controller. As this is available for iOS9+ and I want to target iOS8+ I am looking to use a WKWebView but I can't seem to get the Open in [MyAppName] banner to appear. I'm not aware that this functionality is even possible with WKWebView.

I've messaged Apple to ask them but I find them so slow to reply.

Thanks in advance
Steve

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you solve?

Comment: You could subscribe to the loading events, detect if the CSV of interest is about to open, automatically close the `WKWebView` take the cookie and use it to directly download the CSV. Would also solve the poor user experience as many users aren't aware of "Open In" or the secondary menu if there are too much items.

Comment: How can you subscribe to the loading events? With the WKNavigationDelegate? @FabioPoloni

Comment: @ArielSD Yes, you can use the delegate method `webView(_:decidePolicyFor:decisionHandler:)` to receive a "notification" about a possible load, cancel it and show something else instead.